# Extract substrings from a String

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to shell programming.

I have a String representation of a db connection looking like that:

```
<user>:<password>@<host>
```

And I would like to extract each attribute (user, password and host) from the String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive way to do it would be:

```
$ IFS=:@ read -a args <<< "<user>:<password>@<host>"
$ echo ${args[0]}
<user>
$ echo ${args[1]}
<password>
$ echo ${args[2]}
<host>
```

Obviously, this won't work if the username or password can contain a ':' or '@' character, or if your host happens to be an IPv6 address ;).

Comment: spot on, thank you. And yes, uid and pwd will not contain those delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Bash string manipulation can be done as follow:

```
input="<user>:<password>@<host>"
colonPos=$(expr index "${input}" ':')
atPos=$(expr index "${input}" '@')
user=${input:0:$colonPos-1}
pass=${input:$colonPos:$atPos-$colonPos-1}
host=${input:$atPos}
echo -e "input: ${input}\nuser: ${user}\npass: ${pass}\nhost: ${host}"
```

It also doesn't works with many `:` and/or `@`, but you can play with:

```
tmpStr="${input//[^\:]/}"
colonAmount=${#tmpStr}
tmpStr="${input//[^@]/}"
atAmount=${#tmpStr}
echo -e "colon(s) amount: ${colonAmount}\nat(s) amount: ${atAmount}"
```

Let's play with `if then elif else fi` using those `*Amount` variables to develop your own parser in bash !